# Twilio IVR Setup

Tags: twilio, twilio-twiml, ivr, twilio-functions, twilio-studio

I am creating a Twilio IVR using Twilio Studio.  I've run into an issue that I have not been able to find any relevant documentation on Twilio or the web.  The company is a FinTech that issues debit cards.  So it's imperative that the caller is verified before providing any information or allowing the caller to set or reset their PIN number.

What is the best way to go about authenticating the caller?  i.e the caller has to enter the last 4 digits of the card and the expiration date.  Would it be better to insert the API's into the flow or to build a query to search the database to authenticate the caller?

One more thing, how do I build into the Twilio IVR flow the ability for the caller to change their PIN #.  We have the API's to change their PIN number but I'm trying to figure out if we need to update the API to include the ability confirm and change the PIN number after the caller enters it twice.

I haven't had any success figuring out the solution for my Twilio IVR so I've been unable to test.  Any help the community can provide, I would be in your debt.

Answer (score 0):

> What is the best way to go about authenticating the caller?

Think of Twilio Studio as the connector between your API and a phone call. You can use the Twilio Studio [Gather Widget](https://www.twilio.com/docs/studio/widget-library/gather-input-call) to collect information from the caller and then use the [Http Widget](https://www.twilio.com/docs/studio/widget-library/http-request) to send that information to your API to validate the caller. What you collect to verify the person is up to your requirements. Your API can then return the validation status to Twilio Studio.

> Would it be better to insert the API's into the flow or to build a query to search the database to authenticate the caller?

These seem to be the same from Twilio Studio's perspective. You will need to use the Http Widget to call the API that changes the PIN or to call an API that reads from the database.

Answer (score 0):

Twilio Evangelist here.

In this case the best approach is to build your own API to create the authentication methods that you would like. For example, you could validate the identity of the user by asking the customer their ID and a password saved in your database; your API should be able to validate your customer and return any required information.

Use the Gather Widget to collect the information you might need and finally the HTTP Widget to connect your Flow with your API.

Read the following documentation to understand how to read the response of the API call: https://www.twilio.com/docs/studio/widget-library/http-request#how-to-access-variables-from-your-http-response